# What is the recommended way to share resources between source code and tests in java?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, resources

I have some files in the `src/main/resources` folder which are used by the application I'm working on and I copied over several of them to the `src/test/resources` folder so that my tests can access them easily. I was wondering whether this is the best practice when it comes to unit testing or not? For example I could load the resources from `src/main/resources` and in that way my tests would fail if someone changed the source code. What is the best practice for this?

Comment: I would have one copy, unless there is a good reason to copy the files. ie. use `src/main/resources` unless they shouldn't be released.

Comment: is the content of the files in main/resource static? is it ever going to change? If I have a test where the assertions on the returned data are hard coded, for example, a test to check that a string read from a file is what I expect I'd have to hard code the expected string in the assert. If the file under main/resources changes, my test would start failing. General approach for testing is that the test environment should stay the same every and any time I run it.

Comment: If the resource belongs to the main code and you only use it in the test to check the main code against, you should keep it in `src/main/resources`. `src/test/resources` is for stuff that is used for testing only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in `src/main/resources` are available during testing, I've just comfirmed this is the case for me.  You can override these resources by adding them to `src/test/resources` but as far as I'm aware you can't hide them from the tests so it would look as though there is a configuration error on your system.